Grafana Alerts Custom Message
I have multiple Query in Grafana like A, B, C
In my query A, I have this Flux script
from(bucket: "monitor")
  |> range(start: -30m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "google_monitor")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "google_ack")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["agent_host"] == "10.111.1.98")
  |> difference(nonNegative: true) 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: mean, createEmpty: false) 
  |> yield(name: "final_data")

In my query B, I have this Flux script
from(bucket: "monitor")
  |> range(start: -30m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "google_monitor")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "google_ack")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["agent_host"] == "10.111.2.98")
  |> difference(nonNegative: true) 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: mean, createEmpty: false) 
  |> yield(name: "final_data")

In Contact Points, I use Google Chat and I wanted to get the alert message like
If Query A raise an alert, I should get Alert Like
Name: Query A - Server
Agent Host: 10.111.1.98
If Query B raise an alert, I should get Alert Like
Name: Query B - Database
Agent Host: 10.111.2.98
Could you please give me Alert Template to use in Contact Point Message?
